# Mostrar y ocultar imagen desde un recyclerview expandible

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Buen dia,
Solicito de su ayuda o si pudieran orientarme sobre lo que tengo que estudiar, tengo un recyclerview expandible, pero cuando elimino todos los grupos juntos con sus elementos que se despliegan, quiero que me muestre una imagen y un texto en pantalla. Para indicar que no hay elementos a mostrar.

```
class adaptador_expandiblelist internal constructor(val context:Context, val lista_clientes:MutableList<Data_entregas>, val lista_productos:HashMap<Data_entregas,MutableList<Data_entregas>>/):
    BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

override fun getGroupCount(): Intoverride fun getGroupCount(): Int{...}
override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int{...}
override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Data_entregas{...}
override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Data_entregas{...} 
override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {...}
override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {...}
override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean{...}
override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isexpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View{...}


// Metodo donde valido si aun tiene elementos un grupo.
override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLasrChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
       var img=convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView3)
       var Texto=convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.textView12)
       var lista_productos=getChild(groupPosition,childPosition) 

       if(lista_productos[lista_clientes[groupPosition]]!!.isEmpty()){
            img!!.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            Texto!!.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }
        else{
            
            img!!.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
            Texto!!.visibility=View.INVISIBLE

        }
}
override fun isChildSelectable(p0: Int, p1: Int): Boolean {...}

}
```

El error que me da es:  `java.lang.NullPointerException`, pero no me queda claro cual es la razon.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gos.nenimanagerv12, PID: 10456
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.gos.nenimanagerv12.adaptador.adaptador_expandiblelist.getChildView(adaptador_expandiblelist.kt:353)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2067)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:793)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1504)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1802)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2184)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Intente instanciarlo a otra clase pero no me funciono.

Agradezco su atencion a mi consulta.
Saludos.

Comment: NullPointerException en donde, puedes agregar esa parte de tu LogCat?

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys. Actualice la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 353 de adaptador_expandiblelist.kt ?

Comment: esa linea es donde quiero hacer invisible la imagen si es que aun hay datos en la lista, o en su caso hacerla imagen visible es la primera del else: img!!.visibility=View.INVISIBLE

Comment: Jorgesys, podria ser que falta la View, como cuando se crea la variable img?... algo asi: convertView.View.INVISIBLE o convertView.INVISIBLE. Pero aun asi hay algo que me falta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo al error, si este se presenta al cambiar la visibilidad de la vista :

```
img!!.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
```

indica que no encuentra la referencia de la vista ya que el layout usado no contiene el `ImageView` con id `imageView3`:

```
var img=convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView3)
```

asegura que el layout contenga en realidad esta vista.

Comment: Le diste al clavo, Ahi esta el problema, la imagen que intento mostrar esta en otra clase. pero no se como pasarla al Adaptador expandablelistview o viseversa activarla desde el adaptador.

Comment: me puedes apoyar en otra pregunta que recientemente publique?   https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/616948/294929