# Cómo usar viewbinding en un spinner personalizado

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner, android-adapter

Buen dia,

Espero puedan ayudarme, tengo una spinner personalizado, el cual al interior de cada elemento tiene una imagen, nombre, y cantidad de producto, sin embargo lo tengo en una version mas antigua de android y ahora me pide hacer una actualizacion usando ViewBinding.

He buscado informacion y ejemplos pero no se como hacerlo, de antemano se los agradezco mucho.

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
class adaptador_spinner(context: Context,productos:ArrayList<Data_inventario>):ArrayAdapter<Data_inventario>(context,0,productos){

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    return initView(position, convertView, parent)
}

override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    return initView(position, convertView, parent)
}

private fun initView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup) : View{
    val producto=getItem(position)
    val view=convertView?:LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listado_spinner,parent,false)
    val op=BitmapFactory.Options()
    op.inSampleSize=-100
    val bt=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(producto?.foto, op)
    view.imageView6.setImageBitmap(bt)
    view.textView17.text=producto?.nombre
    view.textView58.text=producto?.cant_prod_comprometido
    view.textView60.text=producto?.cant_prod_disponible

    return view
}
```

}

implemente bind, pero en el return no se como devolver la vista o que hacer para que se despliegue la informacion:

```
 private fun initView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup) : View{
    val binding= convertView?.let { ListadoSpinnerBinding.bind(it) }

    val producto=getItem(position)
    val view=convertView?:LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listado_spinner,parent,false)
    val op=BitmapFactory.Options()
    op.inSampleSize=-100
    val bt=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(producto?.foto, op)
    binding?.imageView6?.setImageBitmap(bt) 
    binding?.textView17?.text=producto?.nombre          
    binding?.textView58?.text=producto?.cant_prod_comprometido
    binding?.textView60?.text=producto?.cant_prod_disponible

    return view
}
```